# parameter is always NULL in delete-method, dont know why

Tags: telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

i'm using  telerik mvc 3.

i've got a Grid which is bound to a ViewModel.

```
@(Html.Telerik().Grid<SampleProject.ViewModels.Location.RoomViewModel>()
            .Name("Grid")
            .ToolBar(cmd => cmd.Insert())
            .DataKeys(keys => keys.Add(c => c.RoomId))
            .DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding
                   .Ajax()
                   .Select("Selecting", "Location")
                        .Insert("Inserting", "Location")
                           .Update("Updating", "Location")
                           .Delete("Deleting", "Location" )
                       )
            .Columns(c =>
                {
                    c.Bound(o => o.RoomName);
                    c.Bound(o => o.MaxSeats);
                    c.Bound(o => o.HasScanner);
                    c.Bound(o => o.HasPrinter);
                    c.Bound(o => o.HasFlipchart);
                    c.Bound(o => o.HasBeamer);
                    c.Command(cmd =>
                        {
                            cmd.Edit();
                            cmd.Delete();
                        });
                })
          )
```

the "Inserting"-method works fine (i get RoomViewModel as Parameter). The "Selecting"-Method works too, but the "Deleting"-Method doesnt work.

```
    #region GridActions
    [GridAction]
    public ActionResult Selecting()
    {
        return View(new GridModel(this._currentLocation.Rooms));
    }

    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    [GridAction]
    public ActionResult Inserting(RoomViewModel rvm)
    {
        this._currentLocation.Rooms.Add(rvm);
        return View(new GridModel(this._currentLocation.Rooms));
    }

    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    [GridAction]
    public ActionResult Deleting(RoomViewModel rvm)
    {
        this._currentLocation.Rooms.Remove(rvm);
        return View(new GridModel(this._currentLocation.Rooms));
    }
```

i tried also:

```
        public ActionResult Deleting(int rvm) --> internal error 500 - doesnt hit the breakpoint

        public ActionResult Deleting(string rvm)

        public ActionResult Deleting(object rvm)
```

always "NULL", any idea???

Answer (score 0):

Actually Deleting action method expects entity Identity as a parameter:

```
public ActionResult _DeleteAjaxEditing(int id)
```